# Index is getting injected into itself instead of templateUrl

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, zurb-foundation

Edit: Solution at bottom of question.

So, it would be difficult to provide all the code, because this behavior is only happening in the context of a very large project, but basically instead of my routes showing the templateUrl for the route, the index is getting injected into index, and then that index doesn't show the templateUrl either.

I'm trying to replace the Foundation for Apps routing with vanilla ui-router.  I've followed the steps [here](https://github.com/zurb/foundation-apps/issues/501) to strip out Foundation's routing, but it seems like I'm still having some kind of conflict.

This is absolutely driving me nuts.  My config looks like this:

```
.config(['$stateProvider', $urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
 $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

 $stateProvider
   .state('/', {
     url: '/',
     templateUrl: "<div><h1>Test</h1></div>"
   })
 ;
}])
```

It doesn't matter what I put in templateUrl, it is replaced with the index.html, and I end up with an index inside an index.

Any help would be much appreciated!

SOLUTION:

It looks like, for whatever reason, ui-router injects the index if the path to the template doesn't resolve. (It may also simply inject the parent template, so in this case it is index, but it may be slightly different in other situations, I'm unsure.  Check out the link that Javier Vargas provided in his comment to his answer for more info.)  So if I have:

```
.state('home', {
  url: '/home',
  templateUrl: 'INCORRECT PATH'
}
```

The result in the context of my situation is that the state injects index.html.

For the SPECIFIC problem of routing with ui-router within the context of a Foundation for Apps project, the path to your templates is /templates/myhtmlfiles.html, so the state would look like this:

```
.state('home', {
  url: '/home',
  templateUrl: '/templates/home.html'
}
```

And this is because Foundation for Apps' routing plugin treats "templates" as root, but ui-router treats your working dir as root (this might be "client", "app", etc, but in the context of a Foundation for Apps install it would be one dir above /templates, so you have to add that to the path.)

Thanks to the answers below that helped me sort out why index was getting plopped into the ui-view div (to restate, it was an incorrect path to the template.  If you're having this problem, check the route.  If you need a test, replace templateUrl: with template: 'test' and see if that gets plunked in.)

Comment: I assume in your actual app you are using a URL instead of html for templateUrl? Otherwise you should be using template: instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't you be using **template** besides **templateUrl**?

Comment: I'm confused as to why this is the case, and yes, it works.  Is this because of Foundation for Apps, or has ui-router dropped the url from templateUrl and I'm just looking at old resources? ([here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views), for instance?)

Comment: I am marking this as the answer, because it led me to the correct answer.

Comment: Don't know if this is the best doc place but this link is the one I checked before answering.
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki
IMO if you use templateUrl it will try to fetch the template from a location hosted somewhere. If you want to use inline template you use template.

Comment: Thanks Javier, you led me to what I needed to figure this out.  I'd been looping around for hours! :)